# exim: How to reject spam mail depending on destination domain

Tags: email-server, spam, exim, spamassassin

Currently, I have exim set up to mark spam mail, and reject spam mail with high scores, using these ACL instructions in the `acl_smtp_data` ACL:

```
  warn  condition = ${if <{$message_size}{500000}{1}{0}}
        spam = nobody
        add_header = X-Spam-Status: Yes
  deny  condition = ${if <{$message_size}{500000}{1}{0}}
        condition = ${if >{$spam_score_int}{80}{1}{0}}
        spam = nobody:true
        message = This message scored $spam_score spam points.
```

I’d like to be more aggressive for mails that are destined to certain addresses, e.g. all to `@lists.example.com`, and deny all spam mails to such addresses. Unfortunately, the `domain` acl condition is not available in `acl_smtp_data`. What is the suggested work-around for this?

(I would not mind imposing the more strict behaviour also on messages with multiple recipients, where at least one of them is a lists address.)

Answer (score 2):

You can set an ACL variable in `acl_check_rcpt`, e.g.

```
warn
    set acl_m0 = ${domain}
    logwrite = recipient domain = ${domain}
```

And then you can use $acl_m0 in `acl_check_data`.

Comment: Good idea. But with your code, `acl_m0` would contain the domain of the last recipient. But I guess I could set a variable to `1` if the domain matches in `acl_check_rcpt`, and check the value of that variable in `acl_check_data`.